# What's the magic of those links that will open a new browser like in firefox?

Tags: html, anchor

```
<a ... target="_blank">...</a>
```

This kind of link only opens a new tab,but some websites will open a new browser instance,what's the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox, opening a link in a new tab or window is controlled by the browser's setting. There are ways to manipulate it such as:

```
window.open("", "test", "height=300,width=300,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes")
```

Comment: @compile-fan: You asked for Firefox ;) Don't piss off the users, respect their settings.

Comment: I should say `like in firefox` instead of `in firefox`,my fault:(

Comment: @compile-fan: Or list all of the browsers. Better yet, just don't specify a unique or 'like' browser. There's more than one browser engine.

Comment: so only firefox can open multiple browsers?

Answer (score 0):

If both links are the same in all these websites, so there is a javascript `window.open` get called in the links which open new browser.

It is based on the browser settings, that why I said that if all links looks the same and some act different than other so there is some javascript work.

By the way,

> If you set the target attribute to
>   "_blank", the link will open in a new
>   browser window or a new tab.

Based on the browser settings

Comment: So it's impossible to open a new browser without javascript?

Comment: Go to their house and force them to open it the way you want, rather than the way they want. That's about it.
*edit*Where by the way they want, I mean the way they've configured their browser, which is hopefully the same thing.*